# Implemented `tagged_with` method returning all microposts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have followed Hartl's tutorial to make a ToDoList with a tagging system, also with the help of this [word guide](https://medium.com/@sherzelsmith/add-a-filtering-multiple-tag-system-with-autocomplete-to-your-rails-model-in-rails-5-1bf88cd53e9) and [RailsCast Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBa2qs9CFZQ). However, I do not really understand how the tagging system works in terms of the filtering, so I just copied it and improvised. My best guess is that it's supposed to use the `tagged_with` method, but a console test seems to still display all the microposts.

I have a problem with my filtering system as now it just redirects to a brand new page that contains all tasks including those that doesn't have the clicked tag. This experiment is done on my local computer while clicking tag2.

**Before**
[image: homepage]

**After**
[image: wrong filter]

Here is the log that occurs, and some questions I have about the logs, commented inside

```
Started GET "/tags/try2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-27 17:33:53 +0800
Processing by MicropostsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"tag"=>"try2"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 101], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "try2"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/micropost.rb:13

  Rendering microposts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "microposts"."id" = "taggings"."micropost_id" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1  [["tag_id", 10]]
  ↳ app/views/microposts/index.html.erb:2

  Micropost Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "microposts"."created_at" DESC  [["user_id", 101]]
  ↳ app/views/microposts/index.html.erb:3

  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."micropost_id" = $1  [["micropost_id", 62]]
  ↳ app/views/microposts/index.html.erb:5

  ##The taggings.micropost_id = $1 for some reason here
  ##It's strange why the next even tag loads again for the 2nd time, when there are only 2 tags

  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."micropost_id" = $1  [["micropost_id", 61]]
  ↳ app/views/microposts/index.html.erb:5
  Rendered microposts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (58.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 84.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

Here's my controller code:

MicropostsController

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def index
    @microposts = current_user.microposts
    @microposts = @microposts.tagged_with(params[:tag]) if params[:tag]
    @microposts = @microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "You have deleted a task!"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :tag_list, :tag, 
        {tag_ids: [] }, :tag_ids)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if (@user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]))
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome back, #{@user.name}!"
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
      redirect_back_or root_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

StaticPagesController

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if logged_in?
      @new_micropost = Micropost.new
      @feed_items = current_user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page]) 
    end 
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy]


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end


  def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
     log_in @user
     flash[:info] = "Welcome to the to-do app, #{@user.name}"
     redirect_to @user
   else
     render 'new'
   end
  end

  def admin
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    a = User.find(params[:id]).name
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "#{a} has been deleted!"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end

 def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile for @user.name has been updated"
    redirect_to(@user)
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Update Failed."
    render 'edit'
  end
end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                  :password_confirmation, :admin)
    end
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "You are not logged in. Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if !current_user?(@user)
        flash[:danger] = "You are not authorized to visit this page."
        redirect_to(root_url)
      end
    end
  end
```

microposts/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Filtered Tasks</h1>
<%= will_paginate %>
  <% @current_user.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
    <p><%= truncate(micropost.content, length: 50) %></p>
    <p><small>Tags: <%= raw micropost.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></small></p>
        <span class="timestamp">
            Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
            <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
              <%= link_to "Done", micropost_path(micropost), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Keep up the good work!" } %>
            <% end %>
        </span>
        <br><br>
    <% end %>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

Micropost Model

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings, :dependent => :delete_all
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: {maximum: 140 }
  attr_accessor :tag_list



  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by!(name: name).microposts
  end

  def self.tag_counts
    Tag.select('tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count')
    .joins(:taggings).group('taggings.tag_id')
  end

  def tag_list
    tags.map(&:name).join(', ')
  end

  def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(',').map do |n|
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone have any idea how the tagging system works and in particular why does `tagged_with` return all microposts? Do inform me if more information is needed. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use a propper tagging gem instead of implementing it by hand, check acts-as-taggable-on, it already has a `tagged_with` method https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/0082724158e2f80ddbce095a97afd990a004bf26/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb#L103 and you'll have a lot less headaches. I'm guessing the gem was built around that railscast and the railscast is old an only limited for that example, the gem has more features.

The problem is that your `tagged_with` method does not care about previous scopes, you are throwing them out using a Tag class method instead of building the request using the current scope.

```
def self.tagged_with(name)
  Tag.find_by!(name: name).microposts
end
```

ActsAsTaggableOn handles that the right way.

Comment: I guess I will accept your answer then, it seems nobody has found a working solution to the "code from scratch" method for my case.

Comment: You are using a tutorial from 2012 http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging. Things have changed a lot since then and `acts-as-taggable-on` is based on that tutorial but done for a general use and not just that video.

Comment: Note taken, I thought the source code would be better and suitable to include in any kind of application, especially for a person like me starting out and want to understand how rails work better. I kind of did Hartl's tutorial first and tried extending it using tags. Wonder if it would be easier if I came up with a tagging model then make the rest of the application.